# In Odoo 11, user with inventory management access have also accouting access

Tags: user, accounting

When I create a new user in Odoo 11 and I put "manager" in inventory section, the section "Accounting" gets automatically "Billing".

The user works only in inventory, he doesn't need to see the billing section.

Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.
In the administration part, in the group inventory, the inheritance part, remove the group Accouting/Billing.